# How to create photo-realistic complex plastic material in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, shaders, photorealism

I want to create a plastic material with proper bump and reflection. Something similar to the first image. For bump I used Voronoi texture, but I am having trouble adding small silver dots. And I am not sure that Voronoi texture suits best for plastic. 
How to achieve more photo-realistic material?

[image: My goal]

That is what I have now:
[image: 2]

Comment: It might be a problem with your lighting. Try adjusting the size and strength of different lights. I think the flat look of your material is caused by a lack of highlights and contrast. hope this helps.